# jQuery: make draggable item appear under another draggable item

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

How can I force draggable items to be dropped over other draggable items?

To be clear, I'm making an application about a house planner, and there is two types of items: icons that represent the equipments and shapes that represent the rooms (the plan). The icons must **not** be placed under the floor obviously, so I need the rooms to be always under the icons of the equipments.

Now I know that I have to use `stack: ".theroomsId"` but in my code it runs in a bad way. It applies only to the first room.

Please see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wQ8YA/11/ and tell me what I did wrong.

PS: I'm new to Javascript and jQuery, so you'll find other problems with the code I wrote. Please report if you can.

**EDIT :**

So at the end I didn't use the property stack, I just added `position:absolute` in the CSS file and played with z-index of each element, by giving the higher z-index to the element I wanted to be in front. Learning! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be a common mistake.
The style in js overrides the style in css.

You should just modify the z-index in your js and not in your css because in this case the js overwrites it. I tried it on your example and it seems to work.

Here is an example you can try on:

```
<div id="parent" width="500px" height="500px">
<div id="child1" width="500px" height="500px" style="position:aboslute; top: 0px; left: 0px;background-color:green; z-index:5"/>
<div id="child1" width="500px" height="500px" style="position:aboslute; top: 0px; left: 0px;background-color:yellow; z-index:10"/>
</div>
```

try it and modify the z-index value, the div will normally change from yellow to green

Comment: I don't really know how to manipulate z-index. Can you please explain more or pass a fiddle?

Comment: it's simple, you can assosiate it with the layers in Photoshop. the higher is the z-index value on the higher layer your element is. You can try it by putting to image at the place with absolute, add the attribute z-index and change its value or you can look for some examples about it on google.

Comment: Thanks :) now I understand the utility of z-index